# How can I list the current pages siblings and any ancestor page siblings?

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

For example, if this were my page structure:

```
Food
    Vegetables
    Dairy
    Fruits
        Apples
        Bananas
        Kiwis
        Oranges
Sports
    Hockey
    Baseball
    Football
Entertainment
    Movies
    TV
    Podcasts
```

... and I was on the *Oranges* page, it would display this:

```
Food
    Vegetables
    Dairy
    Fruits
        Apples
        Bananas
        Kiwis
        > Oranges
Sports
Entertainment
```

I'm attempting to use `wp_list_pages()` and its `child_of` option, but it appears to only accept an integer rather than array so I can't just pass what is returned of `get_ancestors($post->ID, 'page')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get top levels page id with following function

```
function find_top_level_id( $post_id ) {
   $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post_id );

    if ( $ancestors ) {
        return end( $ancestors );
    } else {
        return $post_id;
    }
}
```

You can use the returned value with `wp_list_pages()`